# PHPmailer gmail 'from' is gmail account

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a mail with PHPmailer and gmail. But when I send a mail its from my gmail account instead of no-reply. How do I set no-reply as from?

Code I have:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();  

$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = "myAccount@web.com"; 
$mail->Password = "password"; 

$mail->From     = "no-reply@web.com";
$mail->AddAddress($to);  
$mail->AddReplyTo("no-reply@web.com","no-reply");

$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->Body     = $msg;
$mail->WordWrap = 150; 
$mail->send();
```

The mail I get receives (headers):

```
Return-Path: <myAccount@web.com>
```

Which should be no-reply@web.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: John, the answer of @AndrewOdri worked for me! You should try it and mark it as the accepted answer for people reading the post in the future!

Comment: It did work for me too. With a litle tweaking, there are workarounds for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. Just imagine sending mail prompting to reply with your bank account credentials from an address `validation@yourbank.com`.

To have no-reply address you must have an access to the mail server in `@your.domain` (not gmail) and create such account there, then send emails using this account.

Answer (score 5):

There are two options I would recommend trying:

1. Log in to the Google Apps mail account for myaccount@web.com, go to Settings, then Accounts, then Send mail as, and ensure that no-reply@web.com has been validated. I haven't tested this, but this should allow to send mail from no-reply@web.com, rather than from no-reply@web.com on behalf of myaccount@web.com.
2. Actually create a user on Google Apps with the username no-reply@web.com, and send email through that account. If myaccount@web.com needs a copy, you could always BCC the address and setup a filter on no-reply@web.com to forward any failures to myaccount@web.com.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew! This worked for me! Adding the email address your@email.com to your gmail account (and disable Alias) was doing the trick!

Comment: This was great. Not only validated, in my case I needed to set it as the default account. Now all the mail I send via SMTP in php mail using the original account is sent with the alias I specified to act as default. Thank you!